# Duplicate iPhone Simulators Appeared on My Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

A duplicate iPhone simulator just appeared after I deleted `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/CoreSimulator` folder

[image: Duplicate iPhone Simulators]

How to solve this problem?

I've tried to delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode` folder and `~/Library/Application Support/iPhoneSimulator` folder. But all failed.

Comment: Delete XCode.app and try re-installing.

Comment: Deleting Xcode.app and everything under ~/Library/Developer still didn't do the trick.  @nikita-leonov 's answer was the only thing that did the trick for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6.4 showing duplicate 'Simulators' with Unique Id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285059/xcode-6-4-showing-duplicate-simulators-with-unique-id)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It may happen because of multiple Xcode installed or during Xcode upgrades. The only thing that need to be done is to open Xcode -> Window -> Devices select duplicated device and delete it.

Comment: Thank you for that!  It's amazing to me that I could uninstall Xcode, delete everything under ~/Library/Developer, re-install Xcode, and this would still show up.  I generally like to leave my magic system voodoo state on my Windows machines. :P

Comment: Works like a magic! At some point I had 3 duplicated simulators for each version :)

Comment: I wish I had known it was this easy a long time ago. Thanks. :)

Comment: This works, but for some reason, deleting one takes about 10 seconds. I have about 100 duplicates, any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 32):

I have a same issue after installing Xcode beta version.
I found that there are several solution to fix this issue.

## 1. snapshot

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/snapshot

usage : `gem install fastlane; fastlane snapshot reset_simulators`

I solved my problem with this library and it is very simple to use.

## 2. Xcode->Window->Devices

You can check installed simulators and delete them. But it will take too long time if you have many simulators.

## 3. xcrun simctl delete

you can use xcrun command in terminal. But you need to input a specific device name with command.

Comment: I used option 1, and it was a great result. Thanks

Comment: Me too, Option 1. This saved me a lot of time. :D

Comment: reset_simulators  deleted also my iOS 7 simulator  :-(

Comment: Somehow I ended up with 1380 (!) Simulators on my system, and snapshot reset_simulators worked for me as well.  Took a bit to run, but much faster than doing anything manually. :)

Comment: Fastlane for the win, had no idea `snapshot` could do such a wonderful thing. Thanks for the 1-liner. :)

Answer (score 5):

I had kinda a lot! Too many to delete one by one in Devices, thanks Apple for not including multi-select. Don't double tap delete either or you'll crash Xcode. I found a script that could delete duplicates however it only worked if there was only 1 duplicate of each type so didn't work in my case. I therefor edited the script to simply delete all the simulators, and then you can add any you need just by clicking plus in the Devices window.

Save the following as `remove_all_sims.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from subprocess import call

p = Popen(["xcrun","simctl","list","devices"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")

blocks = re.split("--\s+(.*?)\s+--",output)

dic = {}

i=0
for block in blocks:

    matches = re.findall("iOS 8.4",block)    
    if len(matches)>0:
        content = blocks[i+1]

        lines = content.split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line)>0:
                match = re.match("(.*?)\(",line)
                if match:
                    devicename = match.group(1)

                    idMatch = re.match(".*?\((.*?)\).*",line)

                    dic[devicename] = idMatch.group(1)
                    call(["xcrun","simctl","delete",idMatch.group(1)])
                    # print match.group(1)
                # print line

    i = i+1

for guid in dic.itervalues():
    call(["xcrun","simctl","delete",guid])
```

Then run:

```
python remove_all_sims.py
```

Note its hard coded for iOS 8.4 simulators only.

[image: Many duplicates]

Comment: That didn't have any effect for me, even after emptying the trash, quitting Xcode, and relaunching it.

Comment: sorry about that i have updated my answer with a link to a script to remove all simulators, then you can simply re-create any you need afterwards  using the plus button in the Devices window..

Comment: This worked for me and saved me a lot of time, since I had so many duplicates that it took Xcode a few seconds to re-render the list after deleting each one. Thanks.

Comment: just a note that if you have setup simulators for several versions of iOS, you will need to run the script several times, by changing this line:
    content = blocks[i+1]
and adjusting the index to each version in the blocks
in my case, I had to run it 3 times for:

`<br/>
- content = blocks[i+2]<br/>
 - content = blocks[i+4]<br/>
 - content = blocks[i+6]<br/>
`

Comment: if you setup simulators for several versions of iOS, you need to run the script multiple times, each time adapting the 
`content = blocks[i+1]`

In my case, I had to run it 3 times, using:
content = blocks[i+2]
content = blocks[i+4]
content = blocks[i+6]

Comment: also, if you are like me and have installed several versions of Xcode simultaneously, don't forget to run:
`sudo xcode-select --switch "/Applications/Xcode 6.4.app"`
for each version of XCode