# Can't select any simulator on Xcode6.4

Tags: ios, xcode

I have installed Xcode6.4, but I can't select any simulators to run.I've tried to select one devices from Product -> Destination. But still didn't work.

[image]

and there are duplicated devices.

[image]

Comment: May be error from 'multiple platforms',Xcode think your target is iOS and macos.

Comment: I think, what you need to do is resize your xcode to full screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the deployment target of your project:

**Project** > **Info** > **Deployment Target**

[image]

Set the **iOS Deployment Target**

The reason why there are duplicates: devices support different iOS versions..
You can check the device information of each to clarify..

If you want to remove the duplicates:
***Menu*** > ***Window*** > ***Devices*** and remove duplicates.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285059/xcode-6-4-showing-duplicate-simulators-with-unique-id) for that..

Answer (score 1):

Your Deployment Target might not selected try this.

Select Project -> Target -> Deployment Info -> Deployment Target 7.0 or 8.0