# Reset iPhone simulators to default?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've somehow collected a long list of iPhone simulators in Xcode:

[image: list]

I'd like to clear this, and restore a simulator for each device model and each installed simulator version, i.e.:

- iPhone 4S (iOS 8.3)
- iPhone 4S (iOS 8.4)
- iPhone 4S (iOS 9.0)
- iPhone 5 (iOS 8.3)
- iPhone 5 (iOS 8.4)
- iPhone 5 (iOS 9.0)

...etc.

How can I do this in an automatic manner? I don't care about losing any data on current simulators.

This question is distinct from the [reported duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285059/xcode-6-4-showing-duplicate-simulators-with-unique-id), because it requires that the simulators be *recreated*, as a clean install of Xcode does. The other question's answers merely *delete* the simulators.

It also requires that the deletion and creation be *automated*, i.e. "click the delete button a bunch of times, then click the add button a bunch of times" is not the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 6.4 showing duplicate 'Simulators' with Unique Id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285059/xcode-6-4-showing-duplicate-simulators-with-unique-id)

Comment: @Kirill The accepted answer there doesn't answer this question, as it will just delete the simulators, without creating new ones.

Comment: While the suggestion on that question of installing `snapshot` and running `snapshot reset_simulators` restored my standard iOS 9 simulators, it did not add simulators for iOS 8 (which I have installed).

Comment: You add simulators by clicking the + at the lower left corner of the window.

Comment: @zaph - I know how to do that, the question specifies "in an automatic manner". While doing it manually wouldn't take *forever*, I'd like to know how to do it quickly if this happens again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Open up a simulator, then in menu bar go to Hardware -> Device -> Manage Devices. You can delete and add new simulator there.

Comment: This requires doing everything manually. I want to restore it to how a clean install of Xcode would set everything up.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, Menu: Window:Devices
or
In the Simulator, Then Menu Hardware:Device:Manage Devices...

Delete (and add) simulators as you need.

To delete click on a simulator, press the delete key, click the OK in the dialog.

To add simulators by clicking the + at the lower left corner of the window and select the attributes you need.

Comment: This requires doing everything manually. I want to restore it to how a clean install of Xcode would set everything up.