# Its too many simulators in Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

i have too many in my xCode application 
i try to delete but just a moment its back to device list
how to remove it.

> xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b)

[pic from my xCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi7JV.png)
[pic from device list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCXxt.png)

Answer (score 3):

Quit Xcode and the Simulator, and say (in the Terminal):

```
$ xcrun simctl delete
```

That will delete them all and now you can start fresh. It's good to do this from time to time...

Answer (score 1):

It may happen because of multiple Xcode installed or during Xcode upgrades. The only thing that need to be done is to open Xcode -> Window -> Devices select duplicated device and delete it.

Copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27812360/596360)